# Entity reference edit link

Tags: entities

I have two simple content types

- Parent
- Child

The *Parent* content type has an unlimited value entity reference field which allows it to reference *Child* nodes.

The *Parent* content type *Manage display* for the *Child* entity reference field is set to "**Rendered entity**".

Now when viewing a *Parent* node, each of its *Children* nodes are displayed as well. Great.

However, I'd like to see an "**Edit**" link next to each *Child* node when viewing a *Parent* node. How can I achieve this? I'm hoping for a hover feature that would pop up a cog icon.

I thought the "**Show links**" option on the field's display settings would show some type of link(s), but it appears none are showing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hate to answer my own question, but all you have to do is enable the "**Contextual links**" module. This is a Drupal core module, and it can be enabled here:

```
admin/modules
```

Or with Drush via:

```
drush en contextual
```

This module is automatically enabled with a "*Standard*" Drupal installation, but if you use a "*Minimal*" installation this module will not be enabled.